# VBA: Click option on dropdown list from website

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

Am sorry if it may be very simple, I am a newbie, but I have researched a lot without finding how to click this option (XBT/USD) inside the dropdown list:
https://ibb.co/jqf7zk

I only have managed to display the list with the code below, but I don't know how to select XBT/USD because this doesn't have an ID on html source.

```
Option Explicit
Sub BrowseToSite()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim oSelect As HTMLInputButtonElement
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://www.kraken.com/charts"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("pairselect-button").Click

End Sub
```

HTML code according to inspect element:

```
< a tabindex="-1" class="currpairs" data-pair-text="XBT/USD" data-pair="XBTUSD">XBT/USD</a >
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable response.

Comment: On my phone, so I can't fiddle with the site very well.  There is a getelementsbyclassname method you can use to return a collection of elements with the class name , you should be able to iterate through those and read the inner HTML until you find the one you want to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You have found the dropdown menu. All you need to do is clicking `XBT/USD`. The easiest method that comes to my mind is using `getElementsByClassName` but you dont have to necessarily use it. You can find them by using xpath or tagname as well.

Well, if you inspect the source you will see there are lots of `class="currpairs"`. If you hover on them, you will see that they belong to each item in dropdown list. `XBT/USD` is the second item in the list. So the missing part in your code is:

`IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("currpairs")(1).Click`

Notice we used (1) after getting the class `currpairs`. This is because counting starts from 0 in list. So (0) represents the first item `XBT/EUR`, and (1) represents the second item `XBT/USD` in the list.

Hope this helps.