# How is it possible to click on an option of a dropdown menu in a website using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I wrote this piece of code that should select the fifth option from a dropdown menu in a web page.

```
Dim title As Variant
Set title = ie3.getElementById("selectedTemplateActivity")

title.selectedIndex = 5
```

Saying that the fifth option in the dropwdown menu is called "Daily Activities"
When I run the code, it is true that the value "Daily Activities" is being populated with the two words "Daily Activities" but it seems like the program doesn't actually CLICK on the options of the dropdown menu.

I am saying this because if i select manually the fifth option of the dropdown menu, some text should appear on the screen as soon as the click is made. 
This is what i am having trouble with. When i run the macro with this code, it is like the fifth option is not being clicked but the dropdown menu takes the value of "Daily Activities"

Please can you let me know how to fix this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Click option on dropdown list from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385385/vba-click-option-on-dropdown-list-from-website)

Comment: The suggested dup is questionable as user has not provided any html to allow us to determine whether an _a_ tag is involved. I think it more likely a dup of their prior question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778281/how-to-access-option-from-dropdown-menu-in-vba. OP Please feed back on clarification questions to prior posts you have made. It is frustrating to see the same problems with this question making it difficult to answer. If you have selected the item you possibly need to FireEvent "onclick" the option element, or "onchange" the select element.

Comment: I agree with @QHarr that op is creating multiple threads with similar issue and op is not following on those older threads and creates new threads without providing the enough information and code. If the issue is same than op should continue on the same thread and there is no need to create a new thread. For your current question try to fire change as suggested by QHarr or try to post your HTML code may help to make a test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access option from dropdown menu in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778281/how-to-access-option-from-dropdown-menu-in-vba)